# SELECT-Statement for displaying a temporary state (two tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am sorry for the title, but I could not find the correct wording.

Situation: I got a schema with two tables:

check_result:

- node_name
- requirement_number
- status
- reason
- source

acceptance

- node_name
- requirement_number
- status
- reason
- valid_from
- valid_until
- acceptor (mail / name...)

So the idea is to show the status of a check consisting of several entries in the check_table, where existing valid acceptances "overlay" the result / status of the check_table. For the beginning, not all information are neccessary. The output should contain:

```
requirement_number | status | reason | source/acceptor
```

How could I achieve this?

Edit: Requested outputs

```
sec_ora_acceptance | CREATE TABLE `sec_ora_acceptance` (
  `node_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `instance_oracle_sid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `req_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('OK','NOK','OPEN','NA') NOT NULL,
  `reason` text NOT NULL,
  `acceptor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `acceptor_mail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `valid_until` date DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
  PRIMARY KEY (`node_name`,`instance_oracle_sid`,`req_no`)
)

sec_ora_result | CREATE TABLE `sec_ora_result` (
  `check_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `req_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('OK','NOK','OPEN','NA') NOT NULL COMMENT 'OK, NOK, OPEN, N(ot)A(pplicable)',
  `reason` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`check_id`,`req_no`)
)
```

Edit#2: Requested Information (example and results)

**I adjusted the columns in the sec_ora_result, to make it easier (no other tables needed for comparison - just the two tables)**
table sec_ora_result:

```
check_id|req_no|status|reason|node_name|instance_oracle_sid|source
1|1|OPEN|Could not be tested automatically|abc|ora1|automatic_security_test
2|4|OK|Software Version is OK|abc|ora1|automatic_security_test
3|5|NOK|There is a Problem|abc|ora1|autotic_security_test
```

table sec_ora_acceptance:

```
node_name|instance_oracle_sid|req_no|status|reason|acceptor|acceptor_mail|date|valid_until
abc|ora1|1|OK|Manual proof|Markus|markus@email.com|2014-02-20|9999-12-31
```

The result should now consist of the following

```
req_no|status|reason|source
1|OK|Manual proof|Markus
4|OK|Software Version is OK|automatic_security_test
5|NOK|There is a Problem|automatic_security_test
```

Regards
Markus

Comment: post `SHOW CREATE TABLE check_result;`,`SHOW CREATE TABLE acceptance;`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
As far as I understand, then you would need something like this...

```
   SELECT SR.req_no, 
            ISNULL( SA.status, SR.status) as Status, 
            ISNULL( SA.reason, SR.reason) as Reason, 
            ISNULL( SA.acceptor,  SR.source) as Source
    FROM sec_ora_result SR 
    left join sec_ora_acceptance SA on SA.req_no = SR.req_no
```

Note that we could use ISNULL because status, reason and acceptor are NOT NULL, so if they are NULL means the whole row is NULL and then we can take the SR field, however, if any of those fields could be null, then you would need a regular CASE WHEN SA.req_no is null then Field1 else Field2 end.

Also, take a look to the key used for the left join, not sure if you are filtering only by req_no or you also need something else...

Comment: I will try this, but I also added the requested information above.

Comment: Thanks, I will also try this. I checked today my old solution, which is kind of slow. There I used coalesce. I will give the feedback on monday.

Comment: yes, for this case, COALESCE and ISNULL are pretty similar (if not the same).

Comment: As said above, I will post the relevant part of the query I already got on monday. Probably you could help me optimizing it, because it's kindo of slow.